# Can such an equation exist?

Tags: calculus, functions

$$y(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\tan\left(\frac{2\pi}{h}x\right)$$
$$L(z)=y(x)z+c$$
I found such an example in a strange maths book in the dusty section of the library. 
It said this equation produces rotating line at a single point. Is this even true or a prank?

Comment: Title of the book?

Comment: Of course the equation exists, you wrote it down. (Well actually there are two equations.) Use a more specific term. This problem statement is unlikely to be correct. Please double check it.

Comment: The Book cover is gone and half of the contents are eaten by termites and the book is so old that even the publication year is not there.@Martín-BlasPérezPinilla

Comment: @YvesDaoust the problem that i found it in some dusty book, and I am putting it in the domain of the most elite people of mathematics on the internet

Comment: @Vinay5forPrime: is it too much asking that you proofread the equations ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a valid equation.

The problem is that $y(x)$ does not even *exists* when $x \neq 0$, so if $y(x)$ is not defined in the first place, neither is $L(z)$.

Another issue is that, even if $y(x)$ was well defined, it is still just a constant in $L(z)$; so $L(z)$ would actually just be a single line with slope $y(x)$ for some $x$, since $x$ is not changing. (Of course, if you take all the lines $L(z)$ as $x$ is varying, then you would get a rotating line if $y(x)$ was well defined. But this should be made explicit)

Presumably the point is that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \tan x$ does not exists because it will take on all values from $\mathbb R$ infinitely often (look at the graph of $\tan x$ to convince yourself of this fact). So probably whoever wrote the equation thought that it represents a rotating line because $y(x)$ will be "taking on" all values from $\mathbb R$ infinite times, thus "rotating" the line $L(z)$. This does not make any sense [1], for the reasons explained above, but it is probably what the author thought.

Or maybe the author specified something else / you are in a particular context where this makes sense.. Even though I can't think of one right now

[1] $y(x)$ should be a *single value*, and equal to the limit (which does not exists). $x$ does not change, nor the value of $y(x)$ does, *while computing the limit* (as the author seems to think). It does not matter that if you bring the argument of the $\tan$ function to $\infty$ you will find all real values, the only value $y(x)$ actually takes on is the result of the limiting procedure. Since the limit does not exists, neither does $y(x)$ (for $x \neq 0$; $y(0) = 0$ instead. This is not interesting though)